# Is C code still considered C++?

Tags: c++, c

The comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200090/how-do-you-convert-a-c-string-to-an-int#200099) got me wondering.  I've always thought that C was a proper subset of C++, that is, any valid C code is valid C++ code by extension.  Am I wrong about that?  Is it possible to write a valid C program that is not valid C++ code?

EDIT: This is really similar to, but not an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145096/is-c-actually-a-superset-of-c#145098).

Comment: Bill I specialized the subject of the other question, because the subject wasn't representative of the question.

Comment: I think you're right.  The purpose of the question (and the answers given) is different enough to keep it open.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In general, yes C code is considered C++ code.

But C is not a proper subset in a strict sense.  There are a couple of exceptions.

Here are some valid things in C that are not valid in C++:

```
int *new;//<-- new is not a keyword in C
char *p = malloc(1024); //void * to char* without cast
```

There are more examples too, but you get the idea.

I previously wrote a more extensive answer in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145096/is-c-actually-a-superset-of-c#145098).

Comment: Technically they compile together (as noted above). But writting C code in a C++ file (aka C with classes) does not mean it is C++. The styles for each language is just so radically different, moving from C to C++ is like learning a new language. Moving from C++ to C is just too painful.

Answer (score 12):

Also note that C99 adds several features which aren't permitted in C++ (or are only supported using vendor extensions), such as builtin `_Complex` and `_Imaginary` data types, variable-length arrays (arrays sized at runtime rather than compile time), flexible array members (arrays declared as the last member of a struct that may contain an unspecified number of elements), and more.

For the exhaustive list of incompatibilities between C and C++, including changes with C99, see http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm.

Answer (score 7):

A few more:

C allows recursive calls to main, C++ does not

`char foo[3] = "abc"` is legal C, not C++

`sizeof('A') == sizeof(int)` is true in C and false in C++

There are even more changes with C99

Edit:
I found a post that lists the majority of the differences. http://c-faq.com/misc/cplusplus.nr.html

Summary of why C is not proper subset of C++:

1. auto conversion from `void *` to any object/incomplete type
2. new keywords (a number of these)
3. due to `struct`s becoming scoped
4. due to `struct` tags becoming `typedef`s
5. due to prototypes being required
6. implicit `int` rules
7. Recursive call to `main`
8. Due to `//` comments
9. due to character literals being type `char` and not `int` etc.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about all 3 of those.  Do you have a reference for C++ not allowing recursive calls to main?  g++ will only complain about it if I add the -pedantic flag.

Comment: I can't find a reference to it, I just remember this came up a lot in comp.lang.c when people came looking for help with C/C++, which caused the regulars to flip out and yell "They are separate languages!"

Comment: Note that // is permitted in C99 - which is the current C standard.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of other things that are valid C but not C++:

```
int func();
func(0,0); //Error in C++, but not in C
```

Also don't underestimate the impact of C++ having more keywords:

```
int new;  //Obviously an error in C++
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first example is wrong. Comeau rejects it. If you provide a parameter list, then you have to honor it. If you leave the parameter list blank, then you can pass any parameters you want.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that sets the two apart and comes up in day to day development is linkage and function name mangling. A C function compiled with a C compiler is not accessible to C++ unless the prototype is marked up with `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct {
     int a, b, c;
} st;

st s = {
    .a = 1,
    .b = 2,
};
```

This is valid C code which does not compile in *most* C++ compilers.  It is not part of the C++ spec as far as I know.  However, some C++ compilers are "liberal" with certain parts of the language and allow things they shouldn't, just as a lot miss out on a few nuances that are in the spec but almost never used.

Comment: I think the reason compilers will accept this is if you set the C99 compatibility flag on, or don't turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be more correct to say that ANSI C is a subset of C++.  Not K&R C.

Comment: K&R C is the colloquial term for pre-standard C (K&R 1st Edn).

Answer (score 1):

See also [Is it true that there is no need to learn C because C++ contains everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145096/).  There is a large common subset of C and C++; there are lots of extensions in C++ that are not in C; there are some bits in C that are not in C++ (mostly the bits you don't want to use); and there are some bits that are in C and C++ but are different.