# Does the Microsoft Visual C++ Express compiler compile C code?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm not sure, will the visual c ++ compiler express edition work for compiling c and if not can someone link me to an easy c compiler to use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work.  C is a subset of C++ (for all but a very small number of exceptional cases).  Any C++ compiler should work with valid C code.

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304088/is-c-code-still-considered-c) for some of the rare examples of C code that isn't valid C++.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a subset. Those small number of exceptional cases are more than you might think. In any case it just so happens that VC++ is *also* a C compiler. Just save the file with the .c extension, and it will by default to C code. Alternatively you can pick the language in project settings

Comment: In a strict mathematical sense, no, C isn't a proper subset of C++.  However, well-written C tends to be valid C++.

Comment: "Some" C++ compilers lack C99 features (but who needs them in *2009*؟)

Answer (score 6):

To add to [Bill The Lizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334774/c-compiler#334778) - any C++ compiler will compile a file using C language rules if the file has a `.c` extension.  This can be overriden to force a file to be compiled as C or C++ using command line options.

This is done with MSVC using the `/Tc` or `/TC` options to compile as C, and the `/Tp` or `/TP` options to compile as C++.

Comment: "any C++ compiler" may be effectively true, but it's not required to be true by any standard.

Comment: @Darron - understood, but this is not really a standards question, it's a tools question.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a free copy of the [Digital Mars C](http://www.digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html) compiler.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bloodshed.net/compilers/index.html

maybe there's something to your liking there.

also there's always gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/

Answer (score 0):

Depends partly on what C you're talking about.  Visual C++ will happily compile C programs (make sure they've got a .c extension, and make sure the "Compile As" option in the "Advanced" part of the "C/C++" property pages is not set to C++ only), but is missing a whole lot of stuff in the C99 standard. If you're interested in the original standard C, Visual C++ will work very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Just small clarification - Visual C++ is not a compiler rather an IDE. The compiler will be cl.exe and as many sad there is no problem to compile C code with cl.
But there is other options like [Windows ports of gcc](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Watcom compiler](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page)