# Using C++ in an embedded environment

Tags: c++, embedded

Today I got into a very interesting conversation with a coworker, of which one subject got me thinking and googling this evening. Using C++ (as opposed to C) in an embedded environment. Looking around, there seems to be some good [trades](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101167) for and against the features C++ provides, but others [Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com/c++-in-embedded.html) clearly support it. So, I was wondering who would be able to shed some light on this topic and what the general consensus of the community was.

Comment: I should add that this discussion is based partly upon our managers reluctance to adopt C++ in most of our libraries. We do "embedded" work, only that it lives on a robot most of the time. 99% of the time, we're not using an RTOS or any systems that have extremely limited memory.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649789/why-artificially-limit-your-code-to-c

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812717/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sort of depends on the particular nature of your embedded system and which features of C++ you use. The language itself doesn't necessarily generate bulkier code than C.

For example, if memory is your tightest constraint, you can just use C++ like "C with classes"  -- that is, only using direct member functions, disabling RTTI, and not having any virtual functions or templates. That will fit in pretty much the same space as the equivalent C code, since you've no type information, vtables, or redundant functions to clutter things up.

I've found that templates are the biggest thing to avoid when memory is really tight, since you get one copy of each template function for each type it's specialized on, and that can rapidly bloat code segment.

In the console video games industry (which is sort of the beefy end of the embedded world) C++ is king. Our constraints are hard limits on memory (512mb on current generation) and realtime performance. Generally virtual functions and templates are used, but not exceptions, since they bloat the stack and are too perf-costly. In fact, one major manufacturer's compiler doesn't even support exceptions at all.

Answer (score 6):

The fear of C++ among embedded developers is largely a thing of the past, when C++ compilers were not as good as C compilers (optimizations and code quality wise).

This applies especially to modern platforms with 32 bit architectures. 
But, C is certainly still the preferred choice for more confined environments (as is assembler for 8 bit or 4 bit targets).

So, it really boils down to the resources your target platform provides, and how much of these resources you are likely to actually require, i.e. if you can afford the 'luxury' of doing embedded development in C++ (or even Java for that matter), because you know that you'll hardly have any issues regarding memory or CPU constraints.

Nowadays, many modern embedded platforms (think gaming consoles, mobile phones, PDAs etc), have really become very capable targets, with RISC architectures, several MB of RAM, and 3D hardware acceleration.

It would be a poor decision, to program such platforms using just C or even assembler out of uninformed performance considerations, on the other hand programming a 16 bit PIC in C++ would probably also be a controversial decision.

So, it's really a matter of asking yourself how much of the power, you'll actually need and how much you can afford to sacrifice, in order to improve the development experience (high level language, faster development, less tedious/redundant tasks).

Answer (score 6):

C++ for embedded platforms is perfectly fine - as long as you treat it as a better C. I love the fact that the language is slightly more structured. You can still do all the things that you want to do with C. Just remember to stick to an embedded C library like Newlib or uClibc.

I particularly like the abstraction that we can build using C++, particularly for I/O devices. So, we can have a class for UART and a class for GPIO and what nots. It is cleaner than having a bunch of functions (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

In my previous company all embedded code was written in a small subset of C code due to security (SIL-2) and memory reasons. By introducing a richer language like C++ in that particular scenario would have maybe cause more trouble than benefits.

In all due respect to C++ (which is a language I really love) but I think C - in our particular scenario - was the better choice.

I bet in some cases C++ is just fine to use for embedded applications but it really depends on the application - there is a difference if your program is controlling a nuclear plant or administrating an address book on your cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "general consensus", only the company I work for (which does a lot of development for mobile phones, car navigation systems, DPFs, etc.).

The main drawback I've encountered to using C++ on embedded platforms as opposed to C is that it isn't quite as portable - there are many more cases of compilers that don't adhere to the standard which can cause problems if you need to build your code with more than 1 compiler or outright have bugs in the implementation. Then there are environments where C++ code simply won't run - BREW's issues with relocatable code and its "native OOP" don't play so well with "regular" C++ classes and inheritance.

In the end, though, if you're only targeting 1 platform, I'd say use whatever you think is "better" (faster, less bugs, better design) for your development - in most cases the issues can be worked around quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what kind of embedded development you are doing. I've done embedded development with both C++, C, and Assembly on various platforms, you can even use Java to write applications on smart phones.

For instance on a smart phone like device that's running Windows CE 5, almost all of the code is C++, including in the operating system. Only small bits are written in C or assembly.

On the other hand I've written code for an MSP430 microcontroller, which was in C, and I probably would have done that in C++ had the compiler been more reliable and standards compliant.

Also I seem to recall a university lecturer of mine talking about writing embedded code in Forth or something. So really any language can do.

Answer (score 1):

Now a days it will all boil down to the C++ runtime support of the platform. You're likely to find a way to compile C++ code down to almost any embedded platform with GCC, but if you can't find a suitable C++ runtime for the platform your efforts will be futile, unless you write your own C++ runtime.

Answer (score 0):

One of the few things I tend to agree with Linus is his opinion about C++ http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57643/focus=57918

Besides this, if you really really want to use C++ you might want to have a look at http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/ which describes Embedded C++, or better to say you should not use in C++ for embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing keeping us with using C++ for a long time was the VxWorks support for it, which truly sucked. That supposidly has gotten better on VxWorks 6 (yes, it's been out a while... good 'ole vendor lock-in and lack of company vision has kept us stuck on VxWorks 5.5).

So for us it's mostly a question of the environment. After that, C++ can obviously be just as good as C... it's a matter of people understanding what their tool does and how to use it. C++ may make it easier to write incredibly inefficient code, but that doesn't mean we have to succomb to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently fighting a problem with exceptions in an embedded Linux application.  We are trying to port software written for a different platform that seemed to support exceptions well, but the new compiler tools (a port of gcc) reports errors when creating the eh_frame.  I was against using exceptions for this tool, but the developer reassured me that modern compilers would support it well.

My opinion is that there are some advantages to C++, but I would stay away from exceptions and the standard template library.  We haven't had problems using virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is suitable for microcontrollers and devices without an OS. You just have to know the architecture of the system and be conscious of time and space constrains, especially when doing mission critical programming.

With C++ you can do abstraction which often leads to an increased footprint in the code. You do not want this when programming for a resource-limited machine such as an 8-bit MCU.

Generally, avoid:

- Dynamic memory allocation because it represents uncertainty in timing
- Overloading
- RTTI because the memory cost is large
- Exceptions because of the execution speed lowering

Be cautious with virtual functions as they have a resource cost of a vtable per class and one pointer to the vtable per object. Also, use const in place of #define.

As you move up to 16 and 32-bit MCUs, with 10s or 100s of MB RAM, heavier features like the ones mentioned above may be used.

So to round up, C++ is useful for embedded systems. A main benefit is that OOP can be useful when you want to abstract aspects of the microcontroller, for example UART or state machines. But you may want to avoid certain features all of the time and some of the features some of the time, depending on the target you are programming for.