# How to judge whether a project is a c or c++ project?

Tags: c++, c

```
wprintf(L"Selecting Audio Input Device: %s\n", 
                            varName.bstrVal);
if(0 == wcscmp(varName.bstrVal, L"IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]"))
{
    ...
}

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                        IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pGrabberF);
```

The above is from a .cpp file ,but as you see its content is quite c-style.

Will you call it a c or c++ project?

Comment: Anyone can take a C-like snippet from a C++ file. It's impossible to determine based on these few lines. Are there any classes being delcared or used? Are templates being used? Any C++ specific libraries being used? Answering those questions will help you more.

Comment: No class and template used.For the 3rd question,pls define C++ specific libraries...

Comment: I don't see a coherent question here.  What does it matter what I call it?

Comment: The wprintf() is speaking that its c++

Comment: @ fahad ,most people won't agree unless you have reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply depends how you compile it.

Some code will compile as both, it's considered C++ code if it gets compiled by a C++ compiler.

[C is NOT an exact subset of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145096/is-it-true-that-there-is-no-need-to-learn-c-because-c-contains-everything/145098#145098) by the way.

Often you can deduce with a fast glance simply by the file's extension, although it's possible to put C code in a .cc extension or .cpp extension and you can also put C++ code in a .c extension, but that would be pretty rare.

Comment: It seems to me visual studio uses the same compiler for c and c++,doesn't it?

Comment: @COMer: For the most part. If you use .c though it will compile as C, and will allow things like implicit casts from `void*`.

Comment: I added one extra line in my post,what about now?

Comment: @COMer: Yes you can still call it a C++ project.  The Win32 APIs are built to work with C and you can also use C++.

Comment: Do you mean all Win32 APIs can be used in both c and c++?

Comment: VC++ is hardly a C compiler. It's awful. However I do believe that C++03 "merged" in C89, and this is what VC++ supports. It's a real shame that your first experience with C is through Windows and MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it a C project because I wouldn't be caught dead using C-style string comparison via raw pointer in C++. Exceptions or other stuff would annihilate that code. A correct solution would be to change bstrVal into a BSTR class, which has an operator== overload for wchar_t*.

Comment: BSTR is not a class, it's a type (OLECHAR*).  Did you mean _bstr_t or CComBSTR?

Comment: That's why I suggested CHANGE it into an RAII self-releasing operator-overloaded class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on linkage. If it's a library intended to be C linkable, it's C. If it requires C++ to link with, it's C++. If it provides both options, it's both.

If however it's not a library, and it requires a C++ compiler to build, it's a C++ project.

### Update0

It's still a matter of linkage. The code you've given will compile under both C and C++.

Comment: I added one extra line in my post,what about now?